# Seeing two mouse cursors

Tags: mouse, 14.10, cursor

So, I was trying to drag and drop an image, but for reason I am now stuck with two mouse cursors for some reason (not to mention the image itself is hanging around). image to explain (photo cause the cursor doesn't appear in screenshots) :

[image]

As you can see, there's two cursors - they're also flattened out weirdly, and the image that was being dragged is still there. I have no idea what happened. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Displays -> Unknown Monitor -> Turn Off. 
This worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

just go to the display settings and turn off sticky edges !

Comment: Same problem on lubuntu desktop (installed on Ubuntu). Appeared on a single monitor configuration. The setting did not help.

Comment: it also disappears when i clear system cache... i used this cmd  "free && sync && echo 3 >sudo /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free"

Answer (score 7):

turning off and back on fractional scaling worked for me

Comment: This fixed it for me when a 2nd copy of the mouse cursor was stuck on the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Putting krishnan's answer separately, as this seems to occur, even after turning off sticky edges:

```
free && sync && echo 3 >sudo /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this via "Input > Mouse Integration (uncheck)"

Comment: This was all I had to do (for Kali, which is Debian).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and deserves to be a separate answer.

> Displays -> Unknown Monitor -> Turn Off. This worked for me. – Akash Kothawale Dec 19 '16 at 3:16

I turned off and on my secondary display and the excess pointer disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> display -> single screen. But then choose "revert" to restore original settings. The second cursor was removed by this procedure