# Two cursor on my Screen

Tags: mouse, bug-reporting, cursor

So I just install Ubuntu 20.04 and it was working fine for a little time but after some time there is an arrow stuck on Screen and I tried many things shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595565/seeing-two-mouse-cursors#:%7E:text=just%20go%20to%20the%20display%20settings%20and%20turn%20off%20sticky%20edges%20!&text=Same%20problem%20on%20lubuntu%20desktop%20(installed%20on%20Ubuntu).)

But nothing solves my problem so what should I do?
A lot of people said that this is a feature.

[image: Screen picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

Hi Long time ago I got the same problem.

This can be due to crash of Gnome
Don't worry, I fixed it with refreshing my desktop [Relaunching it]

you can try to press `Alt`+`F2` and type `r` and then press `Enter`

Just like shown in picture below.
[image: Refresh]

#### Option 2

As same issue found [Here](https://findnerd.com/list/view/Getting-Two-Mouse-cursor-in-UBNTU/9471/)
you can try to fix it.
The solution is:-

Step 1--> Go to System Settings

Step 2--> Select display settings

Step 3--> Turn off sticky edges

[image: sticky edge]

Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: when i try first time that cursor problem solved but now it happen again and after trying this again it is not working

Comment: @light_1 Yes, it's a temporary Fix. You have to check why your desktop manager id getting crashed again and again. You can also try to turn off ```sticky edges``` in ```settings``` or check the crash log of gnome to find the issue. I am updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: i don't have option of stick edges but i don't how but that second cursor in just gone after sometime i don't know why ubuntu is messing with me but thank you for response